# Handling Bearer Tokens in Azure Pipeline for HTTP Objects

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So in Azure Data Factory, for a pipeline, I had an HTTP object set up for copying data from an API, it was using a basic Password and Username. Now the API uses a bearer token to authorize calls. I've been able to code up a solution in Python, but I really don't know how to get Azure to handle this authentication process, in the Copy step.

Is there a way to call for the bearer token earlier and then pass it as part of the HTTP link service password?

Python Script:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.url.com")

headers = {
    'authorization': "Basic [removed]",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }
conn.request("GET", "/v1/oauth2/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials", headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

import json
datajson = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer " + datajson["access_token"],
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

conn.request("GET", "/data?data-date=2018-12-09", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to [Copy data from an HTTP endpoint by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http), the only supported authentication methods are: **Anonymous**, **Basic**, **Digest**, **Windows**, or **ClientCertificate**.

But, you might be able to do a workaround by using the `additionalHeaders` of the [Dataset's properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#dataset-properties) to pass the bearer token to the **HTTP** endpoint.

To get the token (and even you might be able to get data this way), you could use [Web activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) to perform the **HTTP** requests.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This solution worked, thank you. The additionalHeaders in the HTTP object are enabled to handle dynamic variables so I could call for the token in an earlier step and then pass that token into a subsequent Copy step.

Comment: This answer would be of use if the solution was documented.

Answer (score 2):

I added a header in the UI and it works.
`NAME: Authorization`, `VALUE: Bearer [my_token]`. Generated this code:

```
{
    "name": "PostToSlack",
    "type": "WebActivity",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "url": "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer my_token"
        },
        "body": {
            "channel": "#random",
            "as_user": "True",
            "text": "Hi from ADF!"
        },
        "linkedServices": [],
        "datasets": []
    }
}
```

From UI:

[image]